# Canvas not working for basic Image draw

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I have tried countless times to make my background appear in javascript as I was hoping if anyone was able to help shred some light onto why it will not load anything.

I have edited and changed this countless times today and still can't make it work.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


ctx.height = 512;
ctx.width = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Game Loop

var Time;
function gameLoop() {
    var now = date.now();
    var dateTime = (now - time) / 1000.0;

    update(dateTime);
    render();

    time = now;
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

// image call
function backgroundDraw() {
    backgroundImg = new image;
    backgroundImg.src = 'images/background.png'
    backgroundImg.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 100, 100);
    }
}
backgroundDraw();
```

I am new to javascript and The guides I'm looking at to work with are  http://jlongster.com/Making-Sprite-based-Games-with-Canvas and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Any help would really be appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is setting up the dimension of the canvas.
Use the canvas element to set its width and height.

Change this

```
ctx.height = 512;
ctx.width = 480;
```

to this

```
canvas.height = 512;
canvas.width = 480;
```

Your image instantiation has a typo, change

```
backgroundImg = new image;
```

to

```
backgroundImg = new Image;
```

you can check this fiddle for the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/RL45Z/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry the question is so basic and partly a big mistake on my part (darn typo's).

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.width = "480px"; // missing width
canvas.style.height = "512px"; // missing height
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.height = 512;
ctx.width = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Game Loop

var Time;
function gameLoop() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dateTime = (now - time) / 1000.0;

    update(dateTime);
    render();

    time = now;
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

// image call
function backgroundDraw() {
    backgroundImg = new Image; // construct typo
    backgroundImg.src = 'http://www.artisticadigital.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2014/02/HTML5_Logo_512/14550496.png'
    backgroundImg.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 100, 100);
    }
}
backgroundDraw();
```

I don't understand that you want to do

Comment: I'm looking to load up an image into the canvas I'm creating at the top but for some reason it's not showing when I load the page up. Thanks for taking your time to try and help :) Edit:

Comment: I'm guessing the reason someone choose to down vote this is because you posted back all the code and simply wrote "I don't understand that you want to do" Until you wrote the comment above I hadn't even noticed you changed anything.

Comment: @JoseVega You should explain what you have fixed in the code, rather than posting just the code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First `var Time !== time` in your gameLoop function. Also, you'll want to define your onload function before setting the src on your image element. `new image` needs image to be capitalized: `new Image`. For now I'd comment out your gameLoop since you're just trying to display the image. Doing that and changing image to Image got the image to render for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have the image working now which is great! I'm unclear as to where you found, var Time !== time in my code or was it a suggested addition to my current game loop? I have also re arranged my code block now so the order is correct, Regards li